# Optimizing Performance on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, performance, optimization, memory

I released the first beta version of my iPhone app on TestFlightApp today. Everything is going really well until I notice that the responsiveness of the application is pretty cruddy. Certainly doesn't have a "nice" native feel that I'm going for.

I've been particularly fastidious concerning my memory allocation/deallocation, so I don't think this is the issue. Basically, I don't know where to turn to next in order to improve the performance of my app.

Here's where I think some of my slowdown can be attributed to:

1. Using UIAppearance to customize the looks of most (if not all) UI elements. I use a brand new font, lots of CAGradientLayers, and lots of edits to CALayer in order to draw nice Shadows.
2. Grouped UITableViewCells that display pictures of a map and itemized lists.
3. UITableViewCells whose layouts are updated every time I call layoutSubviews.
4. UITableViewCells with customized heights. For each call of heightForRowAtIndexPath, I need to reconstruct and re-layout the view, returning the exact height each time.
5. Because I programmatically created views, controllers with longer viewDidLoad calls tend to load slower. What code can I offset in the init call?

Does anyone have any hints or tips for dealing with these problems? Or perhaps people have stories about how they dealt with a slowdown in performance when they released their first app?

Comment: Do you load the pictures in your UITableViewCell asynchronous?

Comment: Yes, I do. They're asynchronous calls to my server.

Comment: do you do any form of background processing?

Comment: and... most importantly does it feel continuously sluggish or is it a on and off thing?

Comment: All of the calls to my server are asynchronous. And the sluggishness depends based on the view. Tableviews are definitely a pressure point. And also whenever I have conditional layouts (particularly troublesome with UITableViewCells)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer won't address all of your points, but here are a couple:

1) Make sure you are using [Shadow Paths](http://nachbaur.com/blog/fun-shadow-effects-using-custom-calayer-shadowpaths).  Paths are much, much more performant.

2) Are you using transparency or corner rounding?  If so, try and reduce transparency as much as possible and do not round corners using `CALayer` cornerRadius.  Instead, use a clipping mask in the `drawRect` of the view that needs to be rounded.

4) Perhaps you can cache the height in an array and not have to repeat the calculation, each and every time.  This may/may not scale well depending on the potential number of items, but may be acceptable depending on the use case.

5) Are there views you can reuse?  For example, when I have a custom selection view on a `UITableViewCell`, I only create a single instance held by the controller and reference it in all the cells.

Comment: Using custom fonts without preloading can also be expensive. For example, preloading all ascii symbols from "Chalkduster" takes ~10 seconds on my iPod...

Comment: @Wayne: Thanks for the advice. I will try to start there. Good idea about the height caching, too. It makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @debleek: How do I cache fonts?

Answer (score 0):

Did you run Instruments (or other profiling methodology) to determine where you app is spending most of it's time.  It would be a good idea to do this before optimizing the wrong thing.

Comment: To be honest, I tried running Instruments and didn't get much out of it, although I should be better about it and keep with it. I'll check it out again.